# How to get cardinal of ensembles explicitly

Tags: coq

I am trying to make a function like `Definition cardinality (A : Ensemble U) : nat.`, so that for each ensemble I get its cardinal. I found this to be a challenging problem, and I would like to get some help.

By the way, there is `cardinal U A n` where if `|A| = n` then it becomes true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue is that you cannot define this function for arbitrary sets: you need to assume that `A` is finite. You might use, for instance, the `Finite` predicate in `Coq.Sets.Finite_sets`.  You might be tempted to use the `finite_cardinal` lemma from `Coq.Sets.Finite_sets_facts`, which says that every finite set has some cardinal.  This would require you to extract a natural number out of an existence statement `exists n, cardinal U A n`, which in turn requires some form of the axiom of choice (e.g. `choice` in `Coq.Logic.ClassicalChoice`).

Comment: But I would need a `exist` instead of `ex` to extract the nat. Is there a way to get it?

Comment: Never mind, I'll use `constructive_definite_description` for that.

Comment: @user5876164 Yes, that would be a good way to go about it. That principle is a weaker form of choice that is enough for this case.